# Exclude Crawler from Subdomain with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web-crawler

I want to stop Crawler from crawling the subdomain `tools.subdomain.com` I found a Snippet on the Internet which show following Rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=403,L]
```

How can i manage to block those Crawler on this subdomain, or just allow the current up to date Browser to visit the Subdomain? I Want to manage this through .htaccess, because not every crawler accepts the robots.txt. For the robots.txt i have following rewrite Condition.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =testing.subdomain.com
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robots_testing.txt [L]
```

Cheers

Sven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your server layout.

**Segregated subdomain**

If the subdomain has its own document root, it's enough place an .htaccess file in the subdomain's document root and write the directives you specified in the htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=403,L]
```

**Shared subdomain**

If the subdomain is using the same document root as the toplevel domain, it's enough to add a `RewriteCond` to the above:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tools\.subdomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=403,L]
```

**Please note (1)**: the syntax `^tools\.subdomain\.com$` is needed to match exactly the entire name of the host; besides, since it's a regular expression, dots must be escaped with a backslash.

**Please note (2)**: the syntax of the last `RewriteCond` may vary according to the bots you want to exclude.